# Is it possible to rename a MySQL table name already in the database?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is it possible to rename a MySQL table? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [RENAME TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html)

```
RENAME TABLE `foo` TO `bar`;
```

or [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` RENAME TO `bar`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL Query Browser, you can just right-click on the table, select Edit Table and change the Table Name field and apply the changes.

Comment: i do not recommend using this tool, because it caused many syntax errors ;)